# How to record player data from Unity game and display it on a website?

Tags: javascript, c#, php, html, unity-game-engine

I am developing a VR game in unity. I want the players to make decisions in a scene and once they have completed the scene, their decisions would be sent to a website where the data is converted into a graph. The idea is that every time they run and complete a scene, the data is automatically sent as a new session under their unique ID on the website side. This to be able to see if decisions improve with the user over time. Is this possible and if so, where do I need to look to make this happen. I am new to this so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider reading about REST or SOAP

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

https://www.restapitutorial.com/

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/understanding-using-rest-api/

https://smartbear.com/blog/test-and-monitor/soap-vs-rest-whats-the-difference/

https://raygun.com/blog/soap-vs-rest-vs-json/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp

https://searchapparchitecture.techtarget.com/definition/SOAP-Simple-Object-Access-Protocol

Basically you send messages from your app to a web server and viceversa... each message is an order to the server requesting data or the modification of existing data, this also needs security and OAuth to prevent hacking

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth